# Division width changes in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do have 3 components which are of different width (like 460px, 300px, 240px) one of them shown in image  using css

i need to set the below format when it is 460px (Ex: #DivMain)

when the main width is 300px 2 columns becomes single column for same div #DivMain
when the main width is 240px 2 columns becomes single column for same div #DivMain

below is html format:

```
<div class="DivMain">
      <table>
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  
           <tr> <td> </td> </tr>  ..etc
     </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Ummm... What have you tried??

Answer (score 0):

Consider reorganizing and using CSS media queries. They are the building blocks of responsive design. Tables do not lend themselves well to responsive rendering.

[More Info](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)